ENUM_FLAG EnumProperty OverflowError when trying to use 1 << 31 as a flag value
I have an enum.Flag defined as so:
class SurfaceFlag(Flag):
    Hang = 1 << 0
    Climb = 1 << 1
    ClimbUDRL = 1 << 2
    Cantilever = 1 << 3
    Pole = 1 << 4
    Tightrope = 1 << 5
    Slippery = 1 << 6
    Grippy = 1 << 7
    Pipe = 1 << 8
    NoTeeter = 1 << 9
    Physical = 1 << 10
    Visibility = 1 << 11
    Camera = 1 << 12
    RailSlide = 1 << 13
    Water = 1 << 14
    DoubleSided = 1 << 15
    Flag_16 = 1 << 16
    Nav = 1 << 17
    NonManifold = 1 << 18
    Terrain  = 1 << 19
    Flag_20 = 1<< 20
    Flag_21 = 1 << 21
    Flag_22 = 1 << 22
    Flag_23 = 1 << 23
    
    # Omitted: 24-27 footsound flags handled somewhere more intuitive (todo)

    Flag_28 = 1 << 28
    Flag_29 = 1 << 29
    Flag_30 = 1 << 30

    Gravity = 1 << 31

And I am trying to expose these flags in the UI, using an EnumProperty in a custom PropertyGroup. The property group is defined as so:
def colFlag(flag : glue.SurfaceFlag, description = "Unknown", icon = "QUESTION" ):
    print(flag.value)
    return ( flag.name, flag.name, description, icon, flag.value )

class LiPoMaterialPropertyGroup(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    collisionTypes = [
        colFlag(SurfaceFlag.Hang,
        "Raz can hang from this surface\n\nMust be used on the walls of a surface, not the floor",
        "AXIS_TOP"),

        colFlag(SurfaceFlag.Climb),

        colFlag(SurfaceFlag.ClimbUDRL,
        "Raz can grab onto this surface and climb it in all directions"
        "VIEW_PAN"),

        colFlag(SurfaceFlag.Cantilever),
        colFlag(SurfaceFlag.Pole),
        colFlag(SurfaceFlag.Tightrope),

        colFlag(SurfaceFlag.Slippery,
        "Raz will be forced to slide down this surface regardless of how steep it is"
        "MATFLUID"),
        colFlag(SurfaceFlag.Grippy,
        "Raz will be able to walk up this surface even if it would normally be considered too steep"
        "FORCE_FORCE"),

        colFlag(SurfaceFlag.Pipe),

        colFlag(SurfaceFlag.NoTeeter,
        "Raz will not teeter on edges with this flag\n\nMust be used on the edges of a surface, not the floor",
        "OUTLINER_OB_ARMATURE"
        ),

        colFlag(SurfaceFlag.Physical,
        "Entities will collide with this surface",
        "MOD_SOLIDIFY"),
        
        colFlag(SurfaceFlag.Visibility),

        colFlag(SurfaceFlag.Camera,
        "The camera will collide with this surface",
        "OUTLINER_OB_CAMERA"),

        colFlag(SurfaceFlag.RailSlide),

        colFlag(SurfaceFlag.Water, icon="MATFLUID"),

        colFlag(SurfaceFlag.DoubleSided),

        colFlag(SurfaceFlag.Flag_16),
        colFlag(SurfaceFlag.Nav),

        colFlag(SurfaceFlag.NonManifold),

        colFlag(SurfaceFlag.Terrain),

        colFlag(SurfaceFlag.Flag_20),
        colFlag(SurfaceFlag.Flag_21),
        colFlag(SurfaceFlag.Flag_22),
        colFlag(SurfaceFlag.Flag_23),

        # Omitted: 24-27 footsound flags handled somewhere more intuitive (todo)

        colFlag(SurfaceFlag.Flag_28),
        colFlag(SurfaceFlag.Flag_29),
        colFlag(SurfaceFlag.Flag_30),
        colFlag(SurfaceFlag.Gravity,
        "Raz's gravity will change to match this surface",
        "TRIA_DOWN_BAR"),
    ]

    collisionFlags: EnumProperty(name="Collision Flags",
    options={'ENUM_FLAG'},
    items=collisionTypes,
    description="Collision flags",
    default={"Physical", "Camera"})

But the presence of SurfaceFlag.Gravity, defined as 1 << 31, causes the following to be thrown when the PropertyGroup is registered:
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError: <built-in function EnumProperty> returned a result with an exception set
Exception in module register(): E:\Development\BrainTumblerLink\addons\BrainTumbler\__init__.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Tools\Blender41\4.1\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 444, in enable
    mod.register()
  File "E:\Development\BrainTumblerLink\addons\BrainTumbler\__init__.py", line 58, in register
    register_class(cls)
ValueError: bpy_struct "LiPoMaterialPropertyGroup" registration error: 'collisionFlags' EnumProperty could not register (see previous error)

Update:
Now not looking at this at 5am I've realised by principle mistake was ignoring the wording of the message and not realising I'm not dealing with a uint here. Which would make a lot more sense when dealing with flags but here we are. Anyway, the goalposts as such have changed a bit. I need a way to use this final flag but I have no idea how to get around this. My intention is to have a grid of toggleable buttons to enable/disable these flags per-material. This information will be exported as extra data in a glTF file, which will then be parsed by another tool to convert the glTF to the final target format.
Original question:
I'm fairly new to scripting in Blender and in general I'm green with Python, but this doesn't seem to make much sense to me. Either I'm overlooking something very obvious or there's some strange property to EnumProperty that I don't know about that's somehow causing this. My print confirms that the value is 2147483648 which should clearly be fine, and yet commenting out the SurfaceFlag.Gravity registration in collisionTypes runs with no issue.

it's just a guess, but i think this "Python int too large to convert to C long" means: your flag variable can only have 32(1) bits (which is already quite large) so you have to use at least internally a second variable to push things around. And honestly i am not sure whether this bit shifting is necessary in today's memory size except you put that flag to e.g. variables which appear in biiiiig numbers like attributes on vertices.

@Chris The add-on I'm writing is for working with a pre-existing format used by a C++ game engine - thus I'm constrained to using the flags as they are defined within that format/engine. It's insane to me that flags wouldn't max out as uints instead but here we are I suppose. Is adding a dedicated bool for toggling this flag and just having the UI present it like the other flags really the only option here? If so that's really rough.

Python ints are unbound but C ints (or in this case C long) are bound to 2^31 - 1 = 2 147 483 647. That means you can only have 30 different flag enum values in a flag enum property.

I was misunderstanding a couple things because I wrote this at around 5am but after reviewing it having just gotten up the error itself makes sense but it seems incredibly awkward that I have no way to indicate that this value is a uint. I really need access to this flag but I have no idea how to work around this.

As stated by Chris you'll have to create a second enum property to store flags >= 2^31

If that's the only option then I'll just use a bool since I only need the 1 extra flag. I'll just have to work around it elsewhere. Really annoying but oh well
